# Cannot find a differ supporting object. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I've inadvertently changed some code somewhere and now my posts are no longer being pulled through, can anyone spot the mistake?

Service:

```
  posts: AngularFirestoreCollection<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  getPosts() {
    this.posts = this.db.collection('/posts') as AngularFirestoreCollection<any[]>;
    return this.posts;
  }
}
```

Post Component:

```
  posts: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts = this.firebaseService.getPosts();
  }

}
```

Post HTML:

```
  <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <mat-card class="mat-elevation-z4">
          <img mat-card-image src="{{post.imgUrl}}">
          <mat-card-actions>
              <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>thumb_up_alt</mat-icon></button><span class="counter mat-small">{{post.numberOfLikes}}</span>
              <button mat-icon-button><mat-icon>star</mat-icon></button><span mat-small class="counter mat-small">{{post.numberOfSaves}}</span>
          </mat-card-actions>
      </mat-card>
  </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>``
```

Now I'm getting `Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.`

Comment: try `*ngFor="let post of posts | async"`

Comment: Thanks but now I get.
```InvalidPipeArgument: '[object Object]' for pipe 'AsyncPipe'```

Comment: <img mat-card-image src="{{post[0].imgUrl}}">

Comment: can you show response from `this.db.collection('/posts') as AngularFirestoreCollection<any[]>`?

Comment: As per the OP question and comments in the below answers, for sure he is getting object instead of Array. That is why you are getting `ngfor only supports binding to iterables`. Check the response of service call and content of `posts` to resolve the issue

Comment: Call `valueChanges()` on your collection, then use the `async` pipe in your template, see my solution below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions to fix your problem:

1. `AngularFirestoreCollection` should be passed the item type of your collection, here you an array type (`any[]`), but something like `Post` would be more appropriate.
2. You have to call `valueChanges()` or `snapshotChanges()` on your collection to get an observable of it. `this.db.collection('/posts')` only returns a reference to the collection (an object to manage it) and not the list itself.
3. Then use the `async` pipe in the template to automatically subscribe/unsubscribe from the returned observable.

In your service:

```
export interface Post {
  imgUrl: string;
  numberOfLikes: number;
  numberOfSaves: number;
}

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseService {
  postsRef: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) { }

  getPosts() {
    this.postsRef = this.db.collection('/posts') as AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
    return this.postsRef.valueChanges();
  }
}
```

In your component:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { FirebaseService, Post } from '....';

@Component({ ... })
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  posts$: Observable<Post[]>;

  constructor(private firebaseService: FirebaseService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.posts$ = this.firebaseService.getPosts();
  }
}
```

In your template:

```
<mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let post of posts$ | async">
  ...
</mat-grid-list>
```

Comment: @FullerPrime, it's a convention to denote an Observable